# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: ... during array update operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to *delete* a specific value (a game) from my *array* in my schema, and this is the code:

```
User.update({ userName: user }, { $pull: { games: { _id: deleteItem } } }, function (err, val) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

the schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName: { type: String, index: true, unique: true },
    userPassword: String,
    games: [gameSchema]
});
```

the error:

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mountain.users index: games.password_1
> errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: mountain.users index: games.password_1 dup key: { games.password: null }',
> [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
> }

why is the error apear and how can I solve it?/other way to delete a value from array inside on object

thanks for your help!

Comment: Please  include the following in the post: `db.collection.getIndexes()` output.

Comment: Maybe you have another document, in which `games.password` does not exist. You can consider deleting the index: `user.games.password`.

Comment: @noam I have passwords in all games

Comment: @prasad_ I tried to console it and I got an error "TypeError: User.getIndexes is not a function"

Comment: @ORI, but after your update, there should be no password for this particular game, right? It seems that this has already happened, that someone updated one document to `$pull` the password away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a unique index built on `games. password`  array.

I assume the game you're trying to pull is the last game in the array. and that you already have a document with an empty `games` array.

Hence the value of both of those documents for the index is (null) the same as they both don't exist.

[sparse indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-indexes) exist for this very reason, it allows you to benefit from the `unique` behaviour while only taking under account documents with values that exist.

So basically you have to re-built your index to be a unique + sparse one.